Unexpected TCP connection without server binding the port
I'm trying in a loop to connect to a TCP socket as a client. My expectations are that I should not be able to establish the connnection untill the server binds the socket. However, after arrount 15 to 20 minutes, the script establishes a connection even though no server is running.
My code looks like this:
import socket
import time

# Server details
HOST = 'localhost'  # The server's hostname or IP address
PORT = 34040       # The port used by the server

# Retry interval in seconds
RETRY_INTERVAL = 0.1  # 100 milliseconds

def try_connect():
    i = 0
    while True:
        i += 1
        try:
            with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
                s.connect((HOST, PORT))
                print(f"Connected to {HOST}:{PORT}")
                # If you want to do something after connecting, add the code here
                break  # Exit the loop if connection is successful
        except ConnectionRefusedError:
            print(f"Connection failed, retrying in {RETRY_INTERVAL * 1000}ms, iteration {i}")
            time.sleep(RETRY_INTERVAL)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try_connect()

The expected behaviour is:
The loop will run untill the server binds the port.
Unfortunately, in this situation, after about 15-20 minutes, the script is able to establish a connection:
Connection failed, retrying in 100.0ms, iteration 14113
Connection failed, retrying in 100.0ms, iteration 14114
Connection failed, retrying in 100.0ms, iteration 14115
Connected to localhost:34040

Trying to see what process is acting as the server in this connection with lsof:
user@linux:~$ sudo lsof -i :34040
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
python    3738 root   47u  IPv4  19139      0t0  TCP linux:34040->linux:34040 (ESTABLISHED)

other things I tried are:
netstat -ntcpav | grep 'localhost:34040' and watch -n 0.1 ss -ntap | grep ‘localhost:34040’ to a log file and monitor that log file, but the results were inconclussive at best, none of these tools find a socket that binds the port. The connection just seems to happen.
This was the output of these commands
I've also tried different ports and the issue still occurs (8080, 33000). Also increasing the RETRY_INTERVAL seems to make the problem harder to reproduce, if with 100ms it took, on average, under 20 minutes, with 500ms it takes just under an hour.
My machine is an Linux kernel version 4.9.224 aarch64, but this is also reproducible on 5.4.0-176 x86_64 VM and 6.1.46 x86_64.
I'm seeking insights into why this unexpected connection is happening. Any advice on further steps to diagnose or resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Edit:
Also a tcpdump log:
14:31:33.399814 IP localhost.34026 > localhost.34030: Flags [S], seq 897561866, win 65495, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 2043122074 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
14:31:33.399816 IP localhost.34030 > localhost.34026: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 242264763, win 0, length 0
14:31:33.499948 IP localhost.34030 > localhost.34030: Flags [S], seq 2164477081, win 65495, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 2043122174 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
14:31:33.499952 IP localhost.34030 > localhost.34030: Flags [S.], seq 2164477081, ack 2164477082, win 65495, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 2043122174 ecr 2043122174,nop,wscale 7], length 0
14:31:33.499954 IP localhost.34030 > localhost.34030: Flags [.], ack 1, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 2043122174 ecr 2043122174], length 0
14:31:33.499973 IP localhost.34030 > localhost.34030: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 1, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 2043122174 ecr 2043122174], length 0
14:31:33.499976 IP localhost.34030 > localhost.34030: Flags [.], ack 2, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 2043122174 ecr 2043122174], length 0

To me it seems like the client manages to connect to itself after a lot of tries. Isn't this something that the OS should prohibit in some way?

It is a feature of TCP: if you start connection from both sides, you can make the connection. Because you use same IP and port, when the random origin port is the same as the destination port you may confuse kernel -- or some slow python garbage collection, or also kernel may not have gone the expected timeouts. Your reconnections are way too short for stability/resources

@GiacomoCatenazzi: your comment looks intriguing, but I'm not sure I understand. Are you saying his client is effectively connecting to an earlier version of itself, due to those earlier instances not having had a chance to be cleaned up because of garbage collection lagging or TCP wait state timers?

Possibly. If you check your tcpdump, you see that origin and destination port is the same, so I bet on the parallel start of connection. I'm also puzzled on the reason (bug? feature?) it happens (I assume you did not use non-blocking/async options)

I suppose this could be considered a Linux bug. When allocating the random source port, it should avoid using the destination port if the source and destination addresses are the same.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk "Are you saying his client is effectively connecting to an earlier version of itself" - Not to an earlier version of itself, no. To its current version. The connect() happened to bind locally to port 34040 and then tried to connect to local port 34040. So it effectively connected to itself. See Linux/Unix Socket Self-connection. Short reconnects can lead to port exhaustion. And the reason your attempts to find the connected socket didn't work is because you close the socket immediately after it connects successfully.

If you think you've connected to yourself, then send some unique data for the session and log both the sending and receiving. (I believe the comments above, but why not confirm it with data?)
